# How to store an array object on user computer in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think it might be a silly question to ask but trust me I am really confused and stuck. Actually I have an object array where I am showing different events in a calendar. Object array is stored in localstorage. I want to do something like when a user opens a page, I want to store that array on the user's computer. I know I am storing the array in localstorage so if the same user visits the page from another computer, then the array will be erased. I want data that will persist.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing localStorage in my React application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714648/implementing-localstorage-in-my-react-application)

Comment: Where to find the this data is there is nothing in localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

Because security reasons it's impossible to manipulate files into the file system in a web application, the browser doesn't have this kind of permission.
What you can do is to save your array into a backend, and when the user login, you retrieve this information from your backend.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want the same users to be able to retrieve their data regardless of the machine they access the site from. In order to do so you need to implement some sort of backend that will persist the data. LocalStorage is only local to that computer and won't be accessible from other machines.

AWS Amplify and Firebase are two tools that you might find useful for building backends for persisting user information.